# Edit some excel-cells with clojure docjure

Tags: excel, clojure

I'm trying to edit some cells in a excel sheet with clojure docjure (https://github.com/mjul/docjure).

In the documentation of docjure is shown how to create a new spreadsheet but I don't want to do that. What I'm trying to do is to read out some information of a excel sheet, calculate some new values and then write them back to specific cells of the same sheet.

Well the first two steps are working. I just don't know how to write the values back.

How can I do this?

Comment: see "Example: Create a spreadsheet", change `create-workbook` to `load-workbook` from Reading example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's often useful to take a look at the tests, as they can also document the code to a degree. I found a file that looked relevant: https://github.com/mjul/docjure/blob/master/test/dk/ative/docjure/spreadsheet_test.clj#L126

And in that file I found:

```
(deftest set-cell!-test
  (let [sheet-name "Sheet 1" 
    sheet-data [["A1"]]
    workbook (create-workbook sheet-name sheet-data)
        a1 (-> workbook (.getSheetAt 0) (.getRow 0) (.getCell 0))]
    (testing "set-cell! for Date"
      (testing "should set value"
        (set-cell! a1 (july 1))
        (is (= (july 1) (.getDateCellValue a1))))
      (testing "should set nil"
        (let [^java.util.Date nil-date nil]
          (set-cell! a1 nil-date))
        (is (= nil (.getDateCellValue a1)))))
    (testing "set-cell! for String"
      (testing "should set value"
        (set-cell! a1 "foo")
        (is (= "foo" (.getStringCellValue a1)))))
    (testing "set-cell! for boolean"
      (testing "should set value"
        (set-cell! a1 (boolean true))
        (is (.getBooleanCellValue a1))))
    (testing "set-cell! for number"
      (testing "should set int"
        (set-cell! a1 (int 1))
        (is (= 1.0 (.getNumericCellValue a1))))
      (testing "should set double"
        (set-cell! a1 (double 1.2))
        (is (= 1.2 (.getNumericCellValue a1)))))))
```

I can't test this now but is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Well set-cell! is working for cells which have content already. The problem now is that cells with no content are returning a nil if I try to get their content or try to write in these cells.

Comment: I solved the nil-cell problem by checking up if the cell I want to write is nil and if so I create a new cell with a java call and write than into that cell